# Can't create Rust LinkedList

Tags: list, rust

Why does this not work? I am trying to create an empty list.

```
use std::collections::LinkedList;

fn main() {

    let mut list = LinkedList::new();

}
```

Comment: You **really** should post the *error message* you get when asking for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is:

```
error: unable to infer enough type information about `_`; type annotations or generic parameter binding required [E0282]

let mut list = LinkedList::new();
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

A `LinkedList` is parameterized over the type of element it contains, but there's nothing in this code to tell the compiler what *that* type is.

In a more complete program, this type would usually be inferred because you do something with the collection, such as inserting a value into it:

```
use std::collections::LinkedList;

fn main() {
    let mut list = LinkedList::new();
    list.push_front("hello");
}
```

You could also specify the type explicitly:

```
use std::collections::LinkedList;

fn main() {
    let mut list = LinkedList::<bool>::new();
    // OR
    let mut list: LinkedList<bool> = LinkedList::new();
}
```

Although type inference is the preferred solution.